# how do I fix this in android studio? I am new and learning it from udemy

Tags: android, imageview

ERROR: /Users/guibrilramde/MyFirstUdemy/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_main.xml:19: AAPT: error: '@tools:sample/avatars' is incompatible with attribute src (attr) reference|color.

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageExample"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:src="@tools:sample/avatars"
    tools:srcCompat="@drawable/ab" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your two lines `android:src="@tools:sample/avatars"` and `tools:srcCompat="@drawable/ab"`, which both determine which picture is shown, are contradictory. Delete both and write `android:src="@drawable/ab"` instead. The `ab.png` image must of course be in the `res/drawable` folder.